# Creating a world map scene with cubes in 3D? (WebGL, Three.js, Canvas)

Tags: html, 3d, webgl

I would like to create a world map in 3D perspective like this, including the shadow:
http://www.google.com/zeitgeist/2012/#explore
 (Please wait 3 seconds for it to animate to its position)

On top of the world map, I would like to place simple red cubes (also casting shadows) instead of the markers in the above example.

1. What web standards/frameworks would you use?
2. In pseudo code, how would you achieve the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with pure webGL, but if you wanna code it fast than Three.js

```
create plane
apply world map texture
pixel-shader displacement for country shapes and shadow
red cubes
render shadow map for directional light and apply it to plane
```